# detect mobile user agent using Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mobile, user-agent

I am creating one Rails 3 application , where I am sending out the emails to mobile users, when sending  emails I am appending one img tag along with src url as my Rails Application URL.

Now When user is opening the email, img tag is loaded and request is sent to my Rails Application.

But here the problem is User on mobile devices has to click on show images button or need to enable the displaying of images in their mobile devises, then only img is loaded and request is sent to my Application

I need some way using which when Email is read, the request should be sent to my rails app using the URL appended in the email.

Let me know if anyone has any idea on this.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can force any access to urls in emails. That would be quite a security problem. The user would have to click it for you to receive the request.

By the way, the image thing does not concern only mobile devices. On gmail pc too, images are not loaded by default and the user can decide to show it once or to trust the sender from now on.

Comment: So do you know any way by which I can receive the response from the URL appended in the email content.
I found one way of appending the URL apart from img tag, iframe tag is also available with src attribute, but I tried that also in case of iframe tag, request is not coming to my Rails Application where in in case of img tag it works .

There has to be some way of doing this , apart from sending request through images.

Thanks for your reply.